# How do I unblock guild invites?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Several weeks ago I disabled the possibility for people to invite me to guilds.

Now I want to remove this setting and I cant find it again.

Where is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interface → Social → Block Guild Invites

Comment: Those are on the Interface -> Social -> Block Guild Invites option, now.